# Works with CSS but not Diazo <drop> rule

Tags: css, plone, diazo, plone-5.x

I'm trying to remove the href attribute from a folderish item in the nav tree for a custom view (Plone 5, custom Barceloneta theme).

I can use the same CSS path to get to the link with the attribute I want to drop and it works.

```
.subsection-questions-service-indicator-codes #portal-column-one li a.navTreeFolderish
```

But it doesn't work in this Diazo rule and I don't understand why. (Actually, I can't get anything in #portal-column-one to "drop.")

```
  <drop css:content=".subsection-questions-service-indicator-codes #portal-column-one li a.navTreeFolderish" attributes="href" />
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you have to use `css:if-content`, read [here](http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/advanced.html)

Comment: I tried that too, nothing

Comment: Have you checked if the selectors works on the site without theme applied? Go to debug mode and try to load the page with the parameter `debug.off=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working from [rules.xml](https://github.com/plone/plonetheme.barceloneta/blob/master/plonetheme/barceloneta/theme/rules.xml)? If you're applying styles using a traditional stylesheet, the [docs](http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/basic.html) state that CSS selectors are replaced by XPath selectors.

Of course, seeing some code would allow us to give better feedback.

Comment: Yes, I'm working from the rules.xml. (I was testing the css in stylesheet just to see if I had typos or some error.) CSS3 selectors can be used with the css namespace. What code do you want to see? If you're familiar with Plone, this just the left column nav portlet. The only custom thing in my not-working rule is the ".subsection....."

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. No, I'm not very familiar with Plone. No chance that it's a specificity issue? That's a mighty long selector.